# designing model in MVVM and WPF and state management

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

In my WPF app, I am using MVVM. I am reading from an XML file, deserialize it to an object model and keeping it in memory.

XML File->BusinessObjectModel(Model)->ViewModel

Whenever the viewmodel needs the model I will provide it from the memory.My problem is when I use the model elements in the views it is updating the model in memory(obviously!). I dont want to do that, I want the model updated only when the user clicks OK in the view(or dialog). How is it usually achieved? Should I only provide the viewmodel a clone of the model and not the original reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing a clone of the model object would solve the problem, as you suggested.

Another approach would be to have the property bindings use an [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) of Explicit. Upon clicking Save, you would programmaticcally call UpdateSource on each binding expression. This requires some extra code, which would belong in the View's code-behind since it is code that manipulates UI elements.

Also consider having a property on your VM for each property exposed in the View, where the backing field of the VM property is *not* the wrapped Model object's corresponding property. When the user clicks Save, you could then assign each property from the VM to the Model object. Naturally the controls in the View would be bound to the VM properties, not the Model properties. This is effectively like having a clone, without the extra baggage of supporting cloning in the Model layer.

I'm not suggesting that any of these options are better or worse. It all depends on the context in which they are used.

Comment: Great, I will go for the third suggestion(having a property in VM which is not the model's) as that sounds the easiest.Thank you!